# How to open Pictures folder of Internal Storage in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, directory

I try this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath());
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

But it opens always "Recent" filder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should make it work

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It just open the Gallery but not the internal storage at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is work for me

```
 private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER =  2;
     Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                       startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
```

You need to override onActivityResult method

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            //do operation after picking image
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry. It does not help to open Pictures of Internal Storage.

Comment: okay ,i update my code , actually it will show all images of phone !

Comment: now i changed my code which open gallery with folders, have a look!